# How to fix design in navbar being deleted when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just learning to code and was looking to understand and recreate this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav.

EDIT:

I wanted it to work without using the stylesheet from FontAwesome.

The problem is that it works when I run the code snippet here, but not on my computer. It loses format and does this: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkf7e.png). Does anyone know what I do wrong?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: ;
  width: ;
  padding: ;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color: yellow;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left; 
  display: block; 
  color: red; 
  text-align: ;
  padding: 14px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: ;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: turquoise;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="nb">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <link rel='stylesheet' href="./css/style.css">
        </head>
<header>

</header>   
<body>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="index.html" class="active">Hjem</a>
    <a href="tjenester.html">Tjenester</a>
    <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
    <a href="om-oss.html">Om oss</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>

  <script src="./js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone also explain exactly what this does:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing FontAwesome. Try adding this to your header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: My understanding was that the link was only to import a font, but am I wrong? I tried but it does not seem to fix the problem on my end, also I wanted to make it work without someone else's CSS.

Comment: This stylesheet contains the definition of the CSS classes for ```<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>```. It basically contains the icon you want to show. (for more info on that check out https://fontawesome.com/)

Comment: It's still not working because you have your script in a separate file, but the `<a>` element with the icon links to the embedded script, like in the example you copied it from.

Comment: Aha that makes sense! Do you know how to make it work in the same way without fontawesome.com?

Comment: You can use an image for you icon and draw it yourself.

Comment: Or you can also use "☰"

Comment: Thanks! I understand how to replace it, but how can I make my code work so that the navbar shows everything when I press it? Right now it does nothing when pressed

Comment: ```<script src="/js/javascript.js"></script>``` is your js file in the correct location?

Comment: It is at the bottom of my body. But my thought is to change this to something else: '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>' to make it work?

Comment: As @Maddin pointed out, you need to make sure the script path is correct. `"/js/javascript.js"` doesn't look right unless you're running a web server and you have the **js** folder under the root. If you're just opening a local file, it will try to look in the **js** folder under the root of your file system, and it's probably _not_ where you put your script file. You probably have it under the **js** folder one level down from your HTML. Then, you need to remove the leading `/`.